# Adding zip file to Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to add a zip file which is uploaded to maven repository as a dependency to another maven project. I would like to know how I could accomplish that.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Regards,
Sarat

Comment: You have to give the `<type>zip</type` and usually a `<classifier>whatEver</classifier>`?

Comment: Thanks khmar. That suggestion helped.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the dependency as mentioned below resolved my issue.

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>sampGroupID</groupId>
         <artifactId>sampArtifactID</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <type>zip</type>
         <classifier>bundle</classifier>
      </dependency>
```

Rudraksh